# Problems with media query values in Opera Mobile 12.1

Tags: media-queries

Here's my problem:

I'm using Media Queries to serve different videos (5 different resolutions) depending on the device resolution. In my media queries I'm asking for "width" and "resolution"

Here's the code I use within the HTML5 video element:

```
<source src="640x360_15.webm" type="video/webm" media="only screen and (max-width:532px) and (min-resolution: 144dpi)">

<source src="960x540_15.webm" type="video/webm" media="only screen and (min-width:533px) and (max-width:757px) and (min-resolution: 144dpi)">

<source src="1280x720_15.webm" type="video/webm" media="only screen and (min-width:758px) and (max-width:910px) and (min-resolution: 144dpi)">

<source src="1600x900_15.webm" type="video/webm" media="only screen and (min-width:911px) and (max-width:1120px) and (min-resolution: 144dpi)">

<source src="1920x1080_15.webm" type="video/webm" media="only screen and (min-width:1121px) and (min-resolution: 144dpi)">
```

My Problem (which I'll soon explain) only occurs in Opera Mobile 12.1.

My test devices are:

HTC One S with a physical resolution of 540x960 pixels 
(reported media query resolution in opera mobile: 144dpi and
reported media query width in opera mobile: 360)

Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini with a physical resolution of 480x800 pixels 
(reported media query resolution in opera mobile: 144dpi and
reported media query width in opera mobile: 320)

For the reported media query values i've used this tool: 
http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html

Now the Problem: I would assume that my media queries on both devices lead to the src: "640x360_15.webm! But the src actually is "1600x900_15.webm.  As I already said the problem only occurs in opera mobile. Mobile Versions of Safari, Chrome and Firefox work well.

Do you have any ideas? I'm helpless...

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not every) mobile browsers will do some adjustments to your page if you forget to add the following to your page head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
          maximum-scale=10.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

This will make your media queries work.